# Close the dropdown when click anywhere on application

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to close the dropdown when we click on anywhere on the application. Dropdown created using tippy.js with react framework. I gave position as fixed and important. Here tippy root css taking the width as whole application.I reduced the width i can able to close dropdown.But here problem is when width is rèduced, if the scroll the page the dropdown is floating on the page. How can i solve this.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code ?

Comment: useEffect hook do the job